# Changing Cisco Anyconnect client GUI Text and messages

Tags: cisco-asa, cisco-anyconnect

I tried changing from Configuration > Remote Access VPN > Network (Client) Access > AnyConnect Customization/Localization > GUI Text and Message and also from language localisation..

I have also tried to export the template to local pc and then make the modification.
Then import it back and select the the language which are in use. (I am using en-us). I tried this but its give a error that "Error while reading specified File, Entry en-us cannot be imported"
Although I tried with different language like fr, ru, ja but got the same error.

Then Uninstall anyconnect client and try it again.
But none of solution work for me

Asa 9.14 and ASDM 7.17 and AnyConnect Client 4.10 is running on my system.

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Its working now. I have gone through below steps.

1. I have exported the AnyConnect template file from "Configuration>Remote Access VPN>Language Localization"
2. Modified the file using editor at my local machine according to my requirement.
3. Then imported the template in six different Language to "Configuration> Remote Access VPN> Network (Client) Access > AnyConnect Customization/Localization> GUI Text and Messages" this location

Its working now!